# Making pedometer - Storage value for each day

Tags: android, database, android-studio, storage, android-database

I wanna make a pedometer app. But I don't know already how can i save or store step numbers for each day or each month.

Thanks for your help now.

Answer (score 1):

Use SharedPreferences to save data:

```
 SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getSharedPreferences("MyData", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
 //for save data
 editor.putString("yourDay", yourData);
 //for get data
 sharedPreferences.getString("yourDay", "yourDefaultData");
```

It is saved on SharePreference folder into your app data folder, and you can always access to it just using the same name when you instantiate your SharedPreference.

Comment: I got it. But can i make it automatically? For example with a calendar or something?

Comment: Do you want to do it periodically, where users don't have to open the applicacion?

Comment: Periodically because it have to show your step number every day every week and every month.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to use a database to store the data locally (as in not through a web service) then start here: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html